# jquery .animate not working inside function

Tags: jquery

Maybe someone could help me out. I appreciate any help. I can't seem to get this working. I'm trying to fade out my html audio player when the youtube onPlayerReady function is called. Very simple.

If I place **$("#musicPlayer").animate({volume: 0}, 3000);** outside of the function it works perfectly fine (fades out the audio) but if I place it into my function (*onPlayerReady*) it doesn't work. Any reason why this is happening?

**I've tried this but didn't work either.**

```
document.getElementById('musicPlayer').animate({volume: 0}, 3000);
```

**Here is my function**

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.setPlaybackQuality(<?php echo $quality; ?>)
    event.target.setVolume(<?php echo $volume; ?>)
    // alert('Start playing entry #0 (preloaded).')
    event.target.playVideo()

    // Music player fade out
    $("#musicPlayer").animate({volume: 0}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Does `onPlayerReady` ever execute? Place a `console.log` or something inside of it to test.

Comment: Where do you call `onPlayerReady` ?

Comment: @Gabriel - Yes, 

query-latest.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: (ec[b] || []).concat is not a function
    at hc (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
    at Object.ic (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
    at kc (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
    at HTMLAudioElement.g (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
    at Function.dequeue (jquery-latest.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAudioElement.<anonymous> (jquery-latest.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.queue (jquery-latest.min.js:3)
    at m.fn.init.animate (jquery-latest.min.js:4)

Comment: Is it possible that `#musicPlayer` doesn't exist anymore when `onPlayerReady` is called?

Comment: Yes... https://jsfiddle.net/md57sx02/ and so I tried this too $("#music_player").animate({volume: 0}, 3000);

Comment: Please add your html and complete js code. Also note that `document.getElementById(...).animate(...` won't work because `getElementById()` returns a DOMElement and `animate()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: I got it working! Thanks for your help explaining the above about DOMElement and the jQuery method. I used this instead. https://jsfiddle.net/v815xhau/